# Different output between argv and normal array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, command-line-arguments

For the program given below, why does the first `printf` print different values for `argv` and `&argv`? The second `printf` prints the same value for `a` and `&a`. What is the mechanism by which argument variables passed to the program are stored?

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char * a[10];  
    printf("%d %d\n\n",argv,&argv);
    printf("%d %d",a,&a);  
    return 0;  
}
```

**What is the mechanism of storing command line arguments to an array of strings**

Comment: printf("%d %d",a,&a); here &a and a will point to the same address...so you dont need to print them both. and use %p instead of %d to print the address.

Comment: I think thats because argv pointer is initialized but your a pointer is not so it got the same adress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not about `argv` is special, but about function argument passing. Try this program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int a[])
{
    int b[10];
    printf("foo :%p %p\n",a,&a);
    printf("foo :%p %p\n",b,&b);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a[10];
    printf("main:%p %p\n", a, &a);
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output in my machine:

```
main:0x7fffb4ded680 0x7fffb4ded680
foo :0x7fffb4ded680 0x7fffb4ded628
foo :0x7fffb4ded630 0x7fffb4ded630
```

The first and third line is not surprising since for an array `arr`, `arr` and `&arr` have the same value. The second line needs to be explained.

As you can see, when `a` is passed in the function `foo`, the value of `a` is not changed, but the address `&a` is changed since C functions always pass arguments by value, there will be a local copy of the argument inside the function.

It's the same with `argv` since it's just an argument in the function `main`.

---

**EDIT**: For those who disagrees with me, my answer is not against the other answer. On the contrary, they complete each other. `argv` is a pointer exactly because it's an array that's passed as function argument, and it "decayed" into a pointer. Again, `argv` is not special, it acts no different than other arrays that are passed as function argument, that's the whole point of my example code.

Comment: Nice example code! I just think the `argv` in main has some special place before I see your answer!

Comment: This is not really the answer. For any variable `a` of array type, `&a` and `a` as pointers will *always* have the same address. This is a result of how array types in C work. The difference is that `argv` is not of array type.

Comment: @newacct Then why is `argv` a pointer? Exactly because it's passed as function argument, and "decayed" into a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `argv` and `a` in your example follows from paragraph 6.7.6.3 ad 7 of the C-standard:

> **A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’**, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

As a consequence `argv` is a pointer which has its own address, whereas `a` is an array and `a` points to the address of the first element of the array, which is the same as the address of the array.